XHR FailedというエラーがでてVSCodeの拡張機能が使えない
非常に困っています。
助けてください。
数週間ぶりにデスクトップでVSCode(version 1.89.1)を開いたのですが、何故か拡張機能が表示されなくなっていました。
拡張機能の更新を実行すると「The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: XHR failed」と表示され更新できません。
ネットで検索もしましたが、改善しません。
助けてください...。
既に試したこと

VSCodeの更新
Windowsの更新
VSCodeの再インストール
Http:Proxy Strict SSLという設定のチェック有/無
Http:Proxy Supportの選択(off/on/fallback/override)
モデム(JCOM)の電源抜き差し
netsh winhttp show proxyでプロキシの確認(結果はプロキシサーバーなし)

以上です。
他に必要な情報あったら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

問題の切り分けとして、別の回線(ノートPCであれば、テザリングでつなぐ)でも同じ問題が発生しますか？

コメントありがとうございます。はい、ノートpcでテザリングをしましたが、同様の問題が発生しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/q/70177216/7949528 このあたりの対応は一通りやりつくした感じですかね？

所用により外出しているので2,3日後確認しますありがとうございます。

非常に消化不良なのですが、何もせずに数日後、PCを立ち上げると直っており、拡張機能も問題なくインストールできました。
